# Left Join - All rows tb_unidade

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a select 3 id_unidade columns, txt_unidade, id_membro (remembering that need to charge the 5 lines of tb_unidade even if it is NULL)

tb_unidade

- id_unidade
- txt_unidade
- flag_status

**5 rows**

tb_membro

- id_membro
- txt_membro
- flag_status

**2 rows**

tb_membrounidade

- id_membrounidade
- id_unidade
- id_membro

**2 rows with the same id_membro**

my sql:

```
select un.id_unidade, un.txt_unidade, meun.id_membro
from tb_unidade un
left join tb_membrounidade meun on un.id_unidade = meun.id_unidade
where meun.id_membro = '1' or meun.id_membro is NULL 
order by un.txt_unidade asc
```

Comment: What is your question?  Are you not getting the correct results?

Comment: I need to list all the items tb_unidade however required for what the records contained in the table with id_membro tb_membrounidade ....

OR

Need of txt_unidade according to a id_membro more other txt_unidades that were not selected by the user

Comment: I'm having some difficulty understanding what you need, I assume it's the language barrier. I don't see anything wrong with your SQL. It should give you all records where `id_membro` is `1` or `NULL`. If there are no records where `id_membro` is `1` or `NULL` then you will not get any records back. Are you expecting different results?

Answer (score -1):

you are thinking in the wrong direction

try it like this

```
select
   un.id_unidade,
   un.txt_unidade,
   meun.id_membro  
from
   tb_membrounidade meun       
left join
   tb_unidade un  
      on un.id_unidade = meun.id_unidade  
where
   (meun.id_membro = '1')       
   or
   (meun.id_membro is NULL)   
order by
   un.txt_unidade asc
```

This way you fetch everything by an specfic member then you left join on the unidade

Comment: Tente traduzir melhor sua pergunta, você parece nem saber escrever direito cara o que vc precisa?

Comment: this is an english site. You should write in english.